# USACO Diamond Collector problem failing test cases

Tags: java, algorithm

This is the problem description:

[image]

and here is my code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DiamondCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("diamond.in"));

        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            input.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        String[] nk = input.get(0).split(" ");
        int numDiamonds = Integer.parseInt(nk[0]);
        int maxSizeDiff = Integer.parseInt(nk[1]);

        List<Integer> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < numDiamonds + 1; i++) {
            diamonds.add(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i)));
        }

        Collections.sort(diamonds);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("diamond.out")));
        printWriter.println(getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, 0, maxSizeDiff, 0));
        printWriter.close();
    }

    public static Integer getMaxDiamonds(List<Integer> diamonds, int index, int maxSizeDiff, int total) {
        if(diamonds.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(index == 0) {
            return getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, index + 1, maxSizeDiff, 1);
        }
        else if(index == diamonds.size()) {
            return total;
        }
        else if(diamonds.get(index).equals(diamonds.get(index - 1))) {
            return getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, index + 1, maxSizeDiff, total);
        }

        if(diamonds.get(index) - diamonds.get(index - 1) > maxSizeDiff) {
            return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(total, getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, index + 1, maxSizeDiff, 1)));
        }
        else {
            return getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, index + 1, maxSizeDiff, total + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that for submissions to [usaco portal](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=639), there can't be any comments/javadocs/package information for the grader to accept the submission

I have gone for a recursive approach, trying to break down this "maximum diamond" problem in decision tree fashion.

i.e. max diff of 2, [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]

`getMaxDiamonds` index=0, total=1

`getMaxDiamonds` index=1, total=1

`getMaxDiamonds` index=2, total=2

`getMaxDiamonds` index=3, total=max(2, `getMaxDiamonds([5, 6, 7])`)=max(2, 3)=3

That's how I tried to implement my solution anyway.

Unfortunately this solution is only passing 1/10 test cases, so I'm not sure what I am overlooking here? AFAIK USACO doesn't tell you anything about the test cases that are failing, just that they are failing. Has anyone solved this problem before and/or can see where I went wrong in my solution?

Comment: upon reading the problem more closely, it seems like every diamond must be within a certain range of every other diamond, not just at least one diamond... i construed the word "together" to mean in direct proximity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was right - the wording on these words problems are tricky, so I'll definitely have to spend more time reading the problem next time.

This was my passing solution.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DiamondCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("diamond.in"));

        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            input.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        String[] nk = input.get(0).split(" ");
        int numDiamonds = Integer.parseInt(nk[0]);
        int maxSizeDiff = Integer.parseInt(nk[1]);

        List<Integer> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < numDiamonds + 1; i++) {
            diamonds.add(Integer.parseInt(input.get(i)));
        }

        Collections.sort(diamonds);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("diamond.out")));
        printWriter.println(getMaxDiamonds(diamonds, maxSizeDiff));
        printWriter.close();
    }

    public static Integer getMaxDiamonds(List<Integer> diamonds, int maxSizeDiff) {
        int maxDiamonds = 0;
        for(int startIndex = 0; startIndex < diamonds.size(); startIndex++) {
            int currentIndex = startIndex + 1;
            int currentMax = 1;

            while(currentIndex < diamonds.size() && diamonds.get(currentIndex) - diamonds.get(startIndex) <= maxSizeDiff) {
                currentMax += 1;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
            maxDiamonds = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(maxDiamonds, currentMax));
        }
        return maxDiamonds;
    }
}
```